# Is it possible to pass multiple values on the same Viewbag variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a for loop to pass multiple values with the same ViewBag variable to a table in view but it is only passing the last value that For receives.

I have to use the same variable because the FOR loop is supposedly filling a table and I have a ViewBag variable for each column of the table.

View:

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Extintor(es):
            </th>
            <th>
                Nº de Série
            </th>
            <th>
                Marca
            </th>
            <th>
                Agente
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Words)
        {
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    @Html.Display("ID_Extintor")
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    @Html.Display("N_Serie")
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    @Html.Display("Marca")
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    @Html.Display("Agente")
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
</table>
```

Controller (for loop):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
  {
        id = words[i];
        int id2 = Convert.ToInt32(id);

        List<Extintores> lista = db.Extintores.Where(x => x.ID == id2).ToList();
        idcliente = Convert.ToInt32(lista[0].ID_Cliente);

        List<Clientes> clientes = db.Clientes.Where(x => x.ID == idcliente).ToList();

        string numcliente2 = clientes[0].Num_Cliente;
        numcliente = numcliente2;
        numextintor = lista[0].Num_Extintor;
        nome = clientes[0].Nome;

        ViewBag.ID_Extintor = numextintor;
        ViewBag.N_Serie = lista[0].Num_Serie;
        ViewBag.Marca = lista[0].Marca.Nome;

        var id_agente = lista[0].ID_Agente;
        List<Agentes> agentes = db.Agentes.Where(x => x.ID == id_agente).ToList();
        ViewBag.Agente = agentes[0].Nome;
    }
```

Comment: Just use a strongly typed model instead.   This precisely the type of thing ViewBag is not meant for... Of course you could try creating a List<MyCoolModel> and store the entire list in the ViewBag.... But if you have a model why use a ViewBag at all???  So this is where I draw the line on when to use a ViewBag vs a model.  To be honest I have not used ViewBag in a long time. I always just create a model and pass the model to the view using code like @model MyCoolModel

Answer (score 0):

You should create a view model.

```
public class WordsViewModel
{
public string ID_Extintor {get;set;}
public string N_Serie {get;set;}
public string Marca {get;set;}
public string Agente {get;set;}
}
```

In your cshtml
Declare your model

```
@model List<WordsViewModel>

....
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.Display(x=>x.ID_Extintor)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.Display(x=>x.N_Serie)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.Display(x=>x.Marca)
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                @Html.Display(x=>x.Agente)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
....
```

and your controller:

```
// your view model to fill with data
var viewModel = new List<WordsViewModel>();

  for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
  {

        var dataRow = new WordsViewModel();

        id = words[i];
        int id2 = Convert.ToInt32(id);

        List<Extintores> lista = db.Extintores.Where(x => x.ID == id2).ToList();
        idcliente = Convert.ToInt32(lista[0].ID_Cliente);

        List<Clientes> clientes = db.Clientes.Where(x => x.ID == idcliente).ToList();

        string numcliente2 = clientes[0].Num_Cliente;
        numcliente = numcliente2;
        numextintor = lista[0].Num_Extintor;
        nome = clientes[0].Nome;

        dataRow.ID_Extintor = numextintor;
        dataRow.N_Serie = lista[0].Num_Serie;
        dataRow.Marca = lista[0].Marca.Nome;

        var id_agente = lista[0].ID_Agente;
        List<Agentes> agentes = db.Agentes.Where(x => x.ID == id_agente).ToList();
        dataRow.Agente = agentes[0].Nome;

        // add the data row to the list
        viewModel.Add(dataRow);
    }

return View(viewModel);
```

Since I wasn't sure if all your data are strings, or int's, so I just made them strings.  I hope this works for you.